# Rails helper in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following API call in my view which I reuse a lot:

```
<%@products.each do |product|%>
        <%  url_raw = URI.parse("url=#{product.wmt_id}") %>
        <%  url = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_raw).body %>
        <%  if url.empty? %>
            <%  @title          = "Product Unavailable via API" %>
            <%  @url            = "Product Unavailable via API" %>
            <%  @cover_img      = "180X180.jpg" %>
            <%  @price          = "Product Unavailable via API" %>
        <% else %>
        <%  begin %>
        <%      @response1  = JSON.parse(url) %>
        <%  @title          = @response1["ProductName"]%>
        <%  @url            = "{@response1["ProductUrl"]}"%>
        <%  @cover_img      = @response1["ImagePath"]%>
        <%@price = @response1["currentItemPrice"]%>
        <%rescue%>
        <%end%>
        <%end%>
```

What would be the most efficient way to dry up my code my defining this as a method so I can resuse it. Where should this code be placed if I used it in 3 separate view files?

Comment: like you said, in a helper? `app/helpers/` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is used across the same controller, look in `app/helpers/products_helper.rb` (if your controller is named something different, substitute products for your controller name).

If this is used across many controllers it belongs in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` so that all views have access to it.

I suspect that you could reduce your usage of instance variables significantly and the code will be significantly cleaner in a helper. I would suggest loading this data in the *controller* instead of in the view or helpers. That way the view is simply using information it is given instead of causing repeated api calls. Such eager-loading may be impractical for your situation, but at the very least this should not be in the view.